# Change color of geom_line in faceted plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-grid

I want the lines for each country to be the same colour that I manually set. ie. Sweden = Red, USA = Blue, Canada = Green.

How best to do this?

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  date = rep(c(as.Date("1995-01-01"), as.Date("1995-01-01"), as.Date("1996-01-01"), as.Date("1996-01-01")), 3),
  decile = rep(c("d1", "d2"), 6),
  income = c(10, 30, 15, 35, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120),
  country = c(rep("Sweden", 4), rep("Canada", 4), rep("USA", 4))
)

g <- ggplot(df, aes(x = date, y = income)) +
  geom_line(aes(colour = decile), size = 2) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "green", "blue", "black")) 

g + facet_grid(~ country)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: removed mapping distinguishing deciles.

```
g <- ggplot(df, aes(x = date, y = income, group = decile, color = country)) +
  geom_line(size = 2) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("Sweden" = "red", "Canada" = "green", 
                                "USA" = "blue")) + 
  facet_grid(~ country)
g
```

[image]

Comment: But I don't want to change the linetype at all.

Comment: Use `group = decile` instead of `lty = decile` if you want the deciles to plot separately with the same appearance. I used linetype to distinguish them, but you could alternately use alpha, point shape, size, etc.